# Rails - Local Variables versus Instance Variables

Tags: ruby

while learning Rails, I keep hearing Local vs Instance but I can't find a definition of the two & the differences. And I'd like to avoid making assumptions.

What are the two and how are they different?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main differences between local and instance variables are as follows

1. local variable has its scope restriction i.e not available to another methods where as instance available to another
2. local and instance variable is also available in view
3. instance variable is separate for each object

Answer (score 36):

The main difference between local and instance variable is that local variable is only available in controller, where as instance variable is available in corresponding views also. The controller and views do not share local variables.

Thanks, Anubhaw

Comment: Example, @name = "Ruby_rails" is an instance variable and          name = "Ruby_rails" is an local variable. Thanks......

Comment: In case this helps anyone: It is possible to set local variables for your templates through the controller this way: `render :index, :locals => { :stuff => @stuff }`