# Ruby on Rails - What is the "Find" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@patient = Patient.find(17)
```

Simply speaking, what does every single piece of this code is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@patient** is the instance variable of the class where this is called. Most likely this happens in your controller, then it's the instance variable of your controller called patient. @-char just indicates the instance variable part.

**Patient**. Rails follows ORM (object-relational mapping), which means that for every database table there is corresponding class. These classes that wrap database tables provide method that perform database table-level operations. Patient here is just the name of the class.

**find** is the class-level method provided by Patient class.

**(17)** is the parameter given to the find method. Rails will search patients-table and tries to find record with id = 17.

Comment: Whats the diference between a instance variable and a normal one?

Comment: @pedrozath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757481/rails-local-variables-versus-instance-variables

Answer (score 3):

Simply saying: This will find `patient data` for `id=17` and set it in `@patient` object.

Hope you understand it.

Comment: In the Patients table (unless you've specified it otherwise). ActiveRecord takes care of binding your Rails objects to their corresponding data base table using conventions in naming.

Comment: @pedrozath, @Abel Tamyo: Abel is right. It will fetch data from Patient table. Means get one row from Patient data table for which id is 17.

Answer (score 2):

The above code fetches a record from the table ('patients' by rails convention) and assigns it to the @patient instance variable.

find is a method that is available to model Patient through inheritance from ActiveRecord::Base

The model Patient directly maps to a table in Database that you have configured in your database.yml
The parameter 17 is matched with the primary key of the table and matching record is returned. Since it matches against primary key only a single record is found, returned.

If no record is found for value = 17, then a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception is thrown.