# What is the difference between @user and user in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, instance

I would like to know what is the difference between `@user` and `user`, like in:

```
@user = User.new
```

and

```
user = User.new
```

Some people say that `@user` with @ is an instance used at views, but I already see this instance at Unit tests.

Is there any difference between then? In purpose or semantic or anything?

Comment: Take a loot at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757481/rails-local-variables-versus-instance-variables). Perhaps it may helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance `@user` at unit tests is not the same instance `@user` at controller, but they're used for similar reasons.

`@` signify instance variables, which are available in all other methods of the instance object.

If in a controller you have

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  apply_another_value_to_user
end 

def apply_another_value_to_user
  @user.nickname = 'Zippy'
end
```

That works.

If instead you do...

```
def new
  user = User.new
  apply_another_value_to_user
end 

def apply_another_value_to_user
  user.nickname = 'Zippy'
end
```

You will get an error "undefined local variable or method 'user'" because `user` is only defined for use within the `new` method.

unit tests use `@user` to ensure a user object can be shared by different methods in the test instance.  Controllers use `@user` to ensure a user object can be shared by different methods (and views) in the controller instance.  It may be that during a test a controller instance is initialized and both `@user` instance variables happen to be created but they are not the same variable.

This is why in a test, to access a controller instance variable, you can't use `@user` directly, you have to use `assigns(:user)` which references the controller instance variable.

```
expects(assigns(:user).not_to be_nil
```

Answer (score 1):

user is defined as local variable. You can reuse user with in the same method but cannot use it in other methods.

@user is instance variable. You can use it in other methods as well.

```
class SomeClass

  def first_method
    user = User.new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def second_method
    # ..
    # You can use @user here.
    # But user is undefined in this method. 
  end

end
```

Comment: So `@user` is like a global instance for the class?

Comment: [@user] is instance variable. Not an instance itself.

Each instance (Object) of that class will have one [@user]. It can be accessed from anywhere within the same instance of the class.