# Passing rails variable to liquid works in console but not in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I want to pass a hash to the render method. In my console everything works fine when I do this:

```
@object = Object.find(params[:id])
@hash_object = @object.to_liquid

@template = Liquid::Template.parse("Welcome to {{object_title}}")
@template.render('object_title' => @hash_object["title"])
```

But when i want to render the page through my controller and pass it through an app-proxy which expects vanilla liquid, the hash-key isn't appearing. But it's interpreted, because the view shows blank space. If it wouldn't work at all, the view would show:"Welcome to {{object_title}}" or don't even load because of syntax errors.

I tried almost every possible way to render the template. The next two tryouts are the ones which do not throw an error, but show only a blank where the title should appear:

```
@pageview = Liquid::Template.parse(File.read(Rails.root + "app/views/app_proxy/show.html.erb"))
render text: @pageview.render('object_title' => @hash_object["title"]), content_type: "application/liquid"
```

And the second one (which I think is a bit cleaner and more rubylike):

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
      render text: @pageview.render('object_title' => @hash_object["title"]), layout: false,  content_type: "application/liquid"
      end
    end
```

Where is the mistake in these renderings or what am I missing?

Comment: When you inspect the class `@hash_object["title"]` does it return `String` or something else? It might be just the case that you tell it `@hash_object["title"].to_s`. I haven't worked with Liquid though, but if for some reason it doesn't read your value from the key, Ruby might have interpreted it as something else.

Comment: The hash method is defined in my model and i checked the type with is_a?(String) which gives me a "true". Nevertheless i added it and deployed it with the same result.

Comment: Ok. I also noticed that you try to render the `.erb` file inside the Liquid and then use it to render `text`. But my question is: What happens if you render raw file instead, so instead `render text` place `render file`? I'm really not used too much to other templating engines apart from HAML and ERB, so this might not be the best advice ever.

Comment: tried it right now as render file with locals. Same result

Comment: sorry, my answer doesn't apply here. I tried another answer. I'll delete this one

Answer (score 1):

@ variables are assigned to an instance of a class, not the class itself, so you need to declare it an "initialize" method (or "setup" method, if a test)

Comment: Thx for the hint. Didn't hear about that at all. Could you provide me a good link for a way to start? I dont know how to handle the short chapter in the gem doc in connection with this topic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757481/rails-local-variables-versus-instance-variables

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. I know the difference between instance and local variables. I meant a link about the initialize method and how and where to build it correctly. The gem doc is really short about that topic.

Comment: I don't think this answer applies here, I added another one. I'll delete this one

Comment: Your first hint really helped me. I think I have to work with tags and drops. I think drops are probably the best solution if Im able to get them running. With tags I would have to code every attribute as own tag method. I think I can save a lot of time writing a class which inherits from Liquid::Drop and define my objects.

Answer (score 0):

`render html:` instead of `render text:`

Comment: check out plain: or html:, don't think text: is supported by the docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html