# Liquid Drop class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, liquid

Im struggeling with liquid since a few days. I have an rails app that is ready to use and i wanted to add shopify's app proxy. The proxy is working but I am not able to pass a variable or an object to render.

For now I tried almost every possible way to render. In my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64033058/passing-rails-variable-to-liquid-works-in-console-but-not-in-view) I got the hint that I have to initiliaze what I want to pass. This lead me to Drop classes. When installing the liquid gem, there were no skeletons where to add everything. The docs are outdated and pretty short about all the things, you have or not have to do (i think the gem is somehow deprecated and some stuff has been removed in the last 20 years).

As I understood the Liquid::Drop class is a layer between the model and the controller which prevents users to access every possible object and attribute possible. This makes sense, but I dont know how to put this together.

**Question 1:** Is the gem 'liquid' the best choice or is 'liquid-rails' the better way?

I wrote a class ObjectDrop < Liquid::Drop class and saved it as objects.rb in my models folder

```
class ObjectDrop < Liquid::Drop
  def initiliaze(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def name
    @object["obj_name"]
  end
end
```

I saved it in my models folder, which I guess is wrong, because I still dont see the attributes after rendering.

**Question 2:** Where do I have to save this class and what is the naming convention for the files?

I call the methods through my app_proxy Controller. Just to be sure there is no mistake, here's the code:

```
def show
  @object = Object.find(params[:id])
  
  file = File.read(Rails.root + "app/views/app_proxy/show.html.erb")
  @template = Liquid::Template.parse(file)
  @template.assigns['object'] = ObjectDrop.new(@object)
  @template.render(layout: false, content_type: 'application/liquid')
end
```

Please tell me how to solve this, it really drives me crazy. Any hint or idea is appreciated.