# Using number_to_currency with user parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code

```
<td><%= number_to_currency(x['quote']['USD']['price'], :unit => '$', :separator =>'.', :delimiter => ',', precision: 4)  %><br/></td>
```

When I use it just like that, it is ok, extract the info and put it ok. But when I try to multiply with another variable, it send me an error "ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer can't be coerced into BigDecimal", so I was thinking in turn it into a @, but I am not sure how to do it

Comment: What's the value of `another variable`, and what's the final result you want?

Comment: <td>$<%= crypto.cost_per %></td> is what I want to multiply, it comes from a path with a form, so I want the result of multiplying this other column by the one in the post.

Comment: Maybe you need `BigDecimal(x['quote']['USD']['price'])`?

Comment: now it shows me this error "can't omit precision for a Float."

Comment: Consider using the [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem when working with monetary values. Unlike float, it doesn't have precision issues and you can _calculate_ with it, e.g. multiply a money object by a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think `number_to_currency` returns a `special string` (e.g. "$ 123.0000"), it can't be multiplied with `number` directly.

You could multiply first, then use `number_to_currency` to format result:

```
<% result = x['quote']['USD']['price'] * crypto.cost_per %>
<td><%= number_to_currency(result, unit: '$', separator: '.', delimiter: ',', precision: 4) %></td>
```

Comment: Riiiight, works perfectly, thank you so much. One last doubt if you dont mind... How coul I turn that "result" into a @result and what could be different between those?

Comment: Sure. `result` is a local variable, `@result` is a instance variable. e.g. If you put them to `index` action within `users_controller.rb`, then `@result` will be available in `users/index.html.erb`, but `result` will not. Both be ok in a view, but use local variable in general. More on [Local Variables versus Instance Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757481/rails-local-variables-versus-instance-variables)

Comment: Thank you again, great tips and explanations. Regards!